# Funcion de JSON para comparar contraseñas no devuelve nada

Tags: php, javascript, json

Poseo un formulario para cambio de contraseña.

Este funciona asi:

1* Al pulsar CAMBIAR se ejecuta el JSON toma la contraseña la HASHEA y luego la compara con el valor HASH de la base de datos

2* SI son iguales este pasaria el valor JSON de 1

3* La accion JAVASCRIPT te mostraria un mensaje dependiendo del valor de la respuesta de JSON, en este caso respuesta.coincide.

No esta mostrando el mensaje ni de error ni de coincidencia de las contraseñas

Aqui los codigos:

JSON comparar:

```
function validarCambio(){
    if($('#txtpassold').val()==""){
       $('#txtpassold').focus();
       alert("Debe ingresar la contrase\u00f1a actual");
       return false
    }

    if($('#txtpassnew').val()==""){
       $('#txtpassnew').focus();
       alert("Debe ingresar la nueva contrase\u00f1a");
       return false
    }

    if($('#txtpassnew2').val()==""){
       $('#txtpassnew2').focus();
       alert("Debe ingresar la verificaci\u00F3n de la nueva contrase\u00f1a");
       return false
    }

    let data = { 
      usuario: $('#txtusuario').val(),
      contrasena: $('#txtpassold').val()
    };
    console.dir(data);
    $.post("./funciones_php_comprobarContrasena.php", data , function( respuesta ) 
    {
    if(respuesta.coincide==1)
    {
    alert("Funciono");
    }else {
    alert("La contraseña actual no es la correcta")
    }
    }, "json" );


}
```

PHP.php

```
     <?php
include_once '__conexion.php';
include_once 'funciones/passwordLib.php';
require "funciones/JSON.php";
?>
<?php
  $usuario = "user"/*$_POST["rusuario"]*/;
  $contrasena_escrita = "12345"/*$_POST["rcontrasena"]*/;

  $stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT hash FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=?"); 
       $stmt->bind_param("s",$usuario);
       $stmt->execute();
       $stmt->store_result();
       $stmt->bind_result($contrasena_actual_hash);
       $stmt->fetch();
       $stmt->close();

  echo "Este es el hash de la BBDD :".$contrasena_actual_hash."<br>";

  $contrasena_escrita_hash = password_hash($contrasena_escrita, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

  echo "Este es el hash de la contraseña escrita :".$contrasena_escrita_hash."<br>";

  if (password_verify($contrasena_escrita_hash, $contrasena_actual_hash)){

   $datos = json_encode(array(
      "coincide" => '1'
    ));
    echo $datos;
  }else
  {
    $datos = json_encode(array(
      "coincide" => '0'
    ));
    echo $datos;
  }
?>
```

Haciendo una prueba me esta devolviendo el HASH del usuario diferente.

es decir, la contraseña guardada tiene un HASH XXYYZZ y cuando la hasheo de nuevo a pesar de ser la misma sale un HASH ZZYYXX

Resultado:

```
Este es el hash de la BBDD :$2y$10$qq/OyzHDG2hTWNhEurF57eZYJc8WwDaDhXKwdEqPPQx62oyj2FlCW
Este es el hash de la contraseña escrita :$2y$10$hMzBUzWxAIBycIax7So8ZeqpdvlovLQsrGYVOAbEQbuIJZ2VVbnlG
tas loco ramon
```

Lo raro es que ya he realizado comprobaciones en otra parte del sistema y no da este problema

Comment: ¿Dónde creas esta variable y le asignas algo: `$contrasena_actual_hash` ? O estoy ciego o no lo veo por ninguna parte.

Comment: @A.Cedano Le di publicar por error, ya modifique

Comment: Ya, pero para usar `password_verify()` no tienes que hashear la contraseña escrita. Ejemplo: `$hash = '$2y$07$BCryptRequires22Chrcte/VlQH0piJtjXl.0t1XkA8pw9dMXTpOq';

if (password_verify('rasmuslerdorf', $hash)) {
    echo '¡La contraseña es válida!';
} else {
    echo 'La contraseña no es válida.';
}`Ver: http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php Si todos modos no funciona haciéndolo así verifica que en efecto el usuario `user` tiene la contraseña que tú crees que tiene en la bd, o sea `12345`, pues podría tener otra.

Comment: @A.Cedano, Ya lo corregi, el problema fue que copie y pegue el codigo de otra funcion , pasa otra cosa, ahora no funciona bien la funcion valiarCambio

Comment: Me alegro de que hayas encontrado una solución. He puesto otra cosa interesante dicha en el Manual. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te muestro un ejemplo de la función `password_verify` que está tomado del Manual de PHP:

```
<?php
$hash = '$2y$07$BCryptRequires22Chrcte/VlQH0piJtjXl.0t1XkA8pw9dMXTpOq';

if (password_verify('rasmuslerdorf', $hash)) {
    echo '¡La contraseña es válida!';
} else {
    echo 'La contraseña no es válida.';
}
?>
```

Es importante resaltar que, de acuerdo al ejemplo, **no es necesario hashear la contraseña escrita para verificarla**.

También, entre las contribuciones del manual se sugiere la siguiente:

> If you get incorrect false responses from password_verify when
>   manually including the hash variable (eg. for testing) and you know it
>   should be correct, **make sure you are enclosing the hash variable in
>    single quotes (') and not double quotes (")**.
>
> ---
>
> Es decir:
>
> Cuando se incluye manualmente la variable `$hash` **es recomendable usar
>   comillas simples `'` en lugar de comillas dobles `"`**, ya que, en ciertas
>   claves podríamos tener un resultado erróneo.

Comment: La funcion javascript no me esta validando el valor que recibe

Comment: ¿Qué no funciona? ¿Ves las alertas pero no pasa los datos o no ves nada?

Comment: No pasa nada, puse un alert al principio y muestra "Ejecutando JSON" pero cuano llega a los alert de comparacion no hace nada

Comment: Bueno... serían otras varias cosas y ya tengo que irme. Prueba si estás recibiendo algo en respuesta, poniendo  `console.log (respuesta);` antes de esto: `if(respuesta.coincide==1)`, debes abrir la pestaña  _Mostrar consola de errores_ en tu navegador para verificar si hay datos. Por otra parte, cuando toque comparar, `1` está siendo pasado como String, por lo que debería ser: `if(respuesta.coincide=="1")` Si no funciona habría que ver lo que hay en la parte HTML, si los `input` tienen los id correctos, etc.

Comment: En mis otras funciones JSON coloco valor="1" y luego comparo si valor==1 y funciona bien, cuano uso console.log no regresa nada el valor de respuesta. usando console.dir el pasa bien el usuario y la contraseña

Comment: Pues ahí ya me perdí. Yo hago los `POST` usando jQuery, pero de otra manera, verificando si el `request` tuvo éxito o no...  ¿Al abrir la consola no te muestra ningún error? A veces la ruta del php es incorrecta, etc.

Comment: no da error por la ubicacion del php, ni da error en consola, donde puedo colocar el console.log

Comment: algo que no observamos, jejeje, cuando pasamos los datos los pasaba como usuario y contraseña y en el PHP esperaba rusuario y rcontrasena